# Using spring data JPA instead of hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Can we use spring data JPA to perform all the database operations?
Can we perform all the complex things like caching, stored procedures etc. using spring data JPA and use spring data JPA in place of hibernate?

All the examples I've come across have only been using spring data JPA with spring boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring data that is named in other answer is something different. It's an umbrella that spans project intended to access databases in some way. Those are spring-data-jpa, spring-data-jdbc...

Spring-data-jpa is spring's component that eases the usage of jpa by, for example, providing `JpaRepository` interface, where you can define methods without implementation, that will be implemented in runtime using their names. This way you can manage your persistent layer without writing a single line of SQL.

Under the hood spring-data-jpa uses some jpa implementation. By default it's hibernate, but it can be changed to openJPA, toplink and others.

Comment: As you said, spring-data-jpa is hibernate by default, that means everything which can be done using hibernate can be done using spring-data-jpa alone as well?

Comment: I didn't say those are the same, I said spring-data-jpa **uses** hibernate. So yes, you can use hibernate's functionality

Answer (score 7):

`Spring data` is not intend to replace `hibernate`.

The purpose of `spring data` is to simplify or remove the `DAO` layer implementations entirely.

`Hibernate` implement the `JPA` specification, but not `spring data`. Also `spring data` can use `hibernate` as an implementation of `JPA` specification.